# Groupby en base a una condicion logica aplicada a una columna DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo el siguiente dataframe:

```
    valor     tipo   entidad
0       1   grande       R
1       2  pequeño       R
2       3  mediano       R
3       4   grande       P
4       2   grande       R
5      42   grande       P
6      12   grande       P
7      21  mediano       P
8      21  pequeño       R
9     424  pequeño       R
10     34  pequeño       P
11     12  mediano       R
12     42  pequeño       R
```

La operación consiste en agrupar los valores de la columna 'valor' por la columna 'entidad' realizando un conteo en base a una condición lógica aplicada a la columna 'valor. En mi caso solamente se cuentan los valores mayores a 3. El resultado debe de ser R=4 y P=5 y lo obtengo tras aplicar el siguiente codigo

```
In []:  df.groupby(['entidad'])['valor'].apply(lambda x: (x>3).sum())

Out[]:  entidad
        P    5
        R    4
        Name: valor, dtype: int64
```

Después de esto debo de agregar el resultado al dataframe original creando una columna llamada 'Cuenta'. Este es el código que yo he usado y su salida

```
In []:  DF=pd.DataFrame(DF)
In []:  DF.reset_index(inplace=True)
In []:  df.merge(DF,on=['entidad'],how='inner')
In []:  df=df.rename(columns={'valor_x':'valor','valor_y':'cuenta'},inplace=True)
Out[]:  
    valor   tipo    entidad cuenta
0    1     grande         R    4
1    2    pequeño         R    4
2    3    mediano         R    4
3    2     grande         R    4
4   21    pequeño         R    4
5   424   pequeño         R    4
6   12    mediano         R    4
7   42    pequeño         R    4
8   4     grande          P    5
9   42    grande          P    5
10  12    grande          P    5
11  21    mediano         P    5
12  34    pequeño         P    5
```

Este código consigue sacar el resultado que busco, pero me gustaria saber si existe alguna manera mejor y mas compacta de realizarlo sin tener que utilizar la operation merge, solo crear la columna 'cuenta' agregandole un resultado con la misma longitud que el dataframe original.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo usando el método `map()` con una función `lambda` pasando el resultado del `groupby()` como diccionario. Quedaría así:

```
df_agrupado_entidad = df.groupby(['entidad'])['valor'].apply(lambda x: (x>3).sum())

#pasamos a diccionario seleccionando entidad el groupby
dict_agrupado_entidad = df_agrupado_entidad.to_dict()['entidad'] 

#Creamos la nueva columna, mapeando cada valor de nuestro diccionario.
df_original_bancos['cuenta'] = df_original_bancos['entidad'].map(lambda x: dict_agrupado_entidad[x])
```

### Explicación

1. Usamos el método `to_dict()` para pasar el *df_agrupado* a un diccionario
2. Con el método `map()` vamos iterando sobre cada valor de la columna *entidad* y la función `lambda` simplemente es una función que contiene un diccionario y devuelve un valor. En este caso el valor de cada clave pasado por entidad.

### Consejos

- No nombres tus DataFrames de las siguientes maneras *df*, *DF*, *df1*, *df2*, *df_prueba*, etc. Ya que hasta tu mismo te confundirás (ya no te digo los demás que vean tu código). Lo correcto es que asignes nombres que den algún significado de lo que contienen, esto te ayudará a ti a no confundirte y a los demás, y te quitará mucho tiempo de corrección de errores.
- Esto que yo he hecho es otra forma de hacerlo, habrá miles, tu forma es perfectamente correcta y entendible, no tienes porque cambiarla.

Comment: Muchas gracias por aportar otras maneras de hacerlo. Acabo de probar el código y funciona muy bien (si que es cierto que he tenido que quitar ['entidad'] 
en la segunda línea de código que incluyes ya que da problemas... supongo que por no existir una columna llamada así literalmente).
También gracias por los consejos también.